# MySQL query to get desired output

Tags: mysql, sql, database

What I'm getting with my current query:

```
+---------------+--------------------+-------+--------+--------+
|    Name       |       email        | Apple | Orange | Banana |
+---------------+--------------------+-------+--------+--------+
| NULL          | NULL               | YES   | YES    | YES    |
| Molly Weasley | mweasley@gmail.com | YES   | YES    | YES    |
| Viktor Krum   | vkrum@gmail.com    | YES   | YES    | NULL   |
+---------------+--------------------+-------+--------+--------+
```

What I want:

```
+---------------+--------------------+-------+--------+--------+--------------+
|    Name       |       email        | Apple | Orange | Banana | Info Entered |
+---------------+--------------------+-------+--------+--------+--------------+
| Severus Snape | ssnape@gmail.com   |       |        |        | No           |
| Molly Weasley | mweasley@gmail.com | YES   | YES    | YES    | Yes          |
| Viktor Krum   | vkrum@gmail.com    | YES   | YES    |        | Yes          |
+---------------+--------------------+-------+--------+--------+--------------+
```

Basically, Severus Snape has not answered the questionnaire yet (he has no records in the answers table) but I'd still like tho show him (because he received the questionnaire as indicated in the questions table). Apple, orange, and banana would be blank for him (it's showing YES all the way across for some reason).

The query I'm using:

```
SELECT CONCAT(people.firstName, ' ', people.lastName) AS Name, 
people.email, 
MAX(CASE WHEN questions.fruit = 'apple' THEN 'YES' END) AS Apple, 
MAX(CASE WHEN questions.fruit = 'orange' THEN 'YES' END) AS Orange, 
MAX(CASE WHEN questions.fruit = 'banana' THEN 'YES' END) AS Banana 
FROM answers 
LEFT JOIN questions ON answers.questionID = questions.questionID 
LEFT JOIN people ON questions.person = people.person AND questions.questionnaire = '24' 
GROUP BY CONCAT(people.firstName, ' ', people.lastName), people.email 
ORDER BY Name
```

Sample data:

people table:

```
+-----------+----------+--------------------+--------+
| firstName | lastName |       email        | person |
+-----------+----------+--------------------+--------+
| Harry     | Potter   | hpotter@gmail.com  |      1 |
| Ron       | Weasley  | rweasley@gmail.com |      2 |
| Hermione  | Granger  | hgranger@gmail.com |      3 |
| Severus   | Snape    | ssnape@gmail.com   |      4 |
| Viktor    | Krum     | vkrum@gmail.com    |      5 |
| Molly     | Weasley  | mweasley@gmail.com |      6 |
| Oliver    | Wood     | owood@gmail.com    |      7 |
| Remus     | Loopin   | rlupin@gmail.com   |      8 |
+-----------+----------+--------------------+--------+
```

questions table:

```
+---------------+--------+------------+--------+
| questionnaire | person | questionID | fruit  |
+---------------+--------+------------+--------+
|            23 |      1 |         55 | apple  |
|            23 |      1 |         56 | orange |
|            23 |      1 |         57 | banana |
|            23 |      2 |         58 | apple  |
|            23 |      2 |         59 | orange |
|            23 |      2 |         60 | banana |
|            23 |      3 |         61 | apple  |
|            23 |      3 |         62 | orange |
|            23 |      3 |         63 | banana |
|            24 |      4 |         64 | apple  |
|            24 |      4 |         65 | orange |
|            24 |      4 |         66 | banana |
|            24 |      5 |         67 | apple  |
|            24 |      5 |         68 | orange |
|            24 |      5 |         69 | banana |
|            24 |      6 |         70 | apple  |
|            24 |      6 |         71 | orange |
|            24 |      6 |         72 | banana |
+---------------+--------+------------+--------+
```

answers table:

```
+----------+------------+---------------------+-----------------+
| answerID | questionID |        info         |  dateAnswered   |
+----------+------------+---------------------+-----------------+
|       40 |         59 | some info here      | 5/26/2017 19:23 |
|       41 |         59 |                     | 5/26/2017 18:30 |
|       42 |         59 |                     | 5/26/2017 18:29 |
|       43 |         66 |                     | 5/26/2017 18:36 |
|       44 |         66 |                     | 5/26/2017 20:28 |
|       45 |         70 |                     | 5/26/2017 20:28 |
|       46 |         55 | more info here      | 5/26/2017 20:29 |
|       47 |         71 |                     | 5/26/2017 20:29 |
|       48 |         67 |                     | 5/26/2017 20:31 |
|       49 |         64 |                     | 5/26/2017 18:37 |
|       50 |         55 |                     | 5/26/2017 18:46 |
|       51 |         72 |                     | 5/26/2017 18:46 |
|       52 |         72 | another bit of info | 5/26/2017 18:46 |
|       53 |         72 | and more info       | 5/26/2017 18:46 |
|       54 |         61 |                     | 5/26/2017 18:29 |
|       55 |         61 |                     | 5/26/2017 18:30 |
|       56 |         68 | the info            | 5/26/2017 18:36 |
|       57 |         59 |                     | 5/26/2017 19:22 |
|       58 |         66 |                     | 5/26/2017 19:37 |
|       59 |         61 |                     | 5/26/2017 19:37 |
|       60 |         61 |                     | 5/26/2017 18:33 |
|       61 |         68 | this info           | 5/26/2017 18:38 |
|       62 |         68 |                     | 5/26/2017 19:33 |
|       63 |         68 | some more  info     | 5/26/2017 19:42 |
|       64 |         68 |                     | 5/26/2017 19:56 |
|       65 |         60 |                     | 5/26/2017 20:03 |
+----------+------------+---------------------+-----------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change the order:

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(people.firstName, ' ', people.lastName) AS Name, 
    people.email, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN questions.fruit = 'apple' AND answers.questionID IS NOT NULL THEN 'YES' END) AS Apple, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN questions.fruit = 'orange' AND answers.questionID IS NOT NULL  THEN 'YES' END) AS Orange, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN questions.fruit = 'banana' AND answers.questionID IS NOT NULL  THEN 'YES' END) AS Banana 
FROM people 
JOIN questions ON questions.person = people.person AND questions.questionnaire = '24' 
LEFT JOIN answers ON answers.questionID = questions.questionID 
GROUP BY CONCAT(people.firstName, ' ', people.lastName), people.email 
ORDER BY Name
```

Comment: That returns *everyone* from the 'people' table when I only want people returned who received the questionnaire. In the case of questionnaire 24, that would be Severus, Viktor, and Molly. This query also has YES across the board for Severus, Viktor, and Molly when Severus should be blank and Viktor should be blank for banana.

Comment: Then remove the first `LEFT JOIN` for questions (I've updated the answer)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. If I remove that line than I am no longer including the questions table so can no longer refer to "questionnaire 24'. I also lose the data for what the answers actually mean. The questions table has to be included.

Comment: No-no... do not remove it, just change `LEFT JOIN` to `JOIN`. That will limit the response to the group that have `questionnaire 24`

Comment: This is getting closer. It now returns all three of the people's names and emails correctly that are part of questionnaire 24, but I just get "YES" for apple, orange and banana for all three people.

Comment: Works great, thanks! I figured out how to get the info field in there.